# Import Currency values in csv into R

Tags: r, csv, currency

I am trying to import a csv file with several columns of values with "£" and ",".

The data frame for instance looks like:

```
channel1  channel2
£100,000  £400,000
£200,000  £500,000
£300,000  £600,000
```

`read.csv()` has given me an error. I tried to use `sub`/`gsub` after reading the values as characters but it hasn't been working.

Can you please suggest an approach to read this file?

Comment: What error did `read.csv` give? After reading as character, what did you use for your `sub` and `gsub` attempts?

Comment: You could try `colClasses = "character"` as a `read.csv` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to post a couple of lines of un-editted material from the input file. If you really do have commas as separators and also have commas within column values then it's pretty much hopeless. This will bring in quoted values that are separated by commas:

```
 setClass("poundFmt")
 setAs("character", "poundFmt",
     function(from)  as.numeric( gsub(",", "", gsub("£", "", from,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)))

 dat <- read.table(text= "'channel1', 'chan2'
 '£100,000', '£400,000'
 '£200,000', '£500,000'
 '£300,000', '£600,000'" , sep=",", header=TRUE, colClasses="poundFmt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 str(dat)
#---------------------
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ channel1: num  1e+05 2e+05 3e+05
 $ chan2   : num  4e+05 5e+05 6e+05
```